# How to export pages specific fields only like Page Title, Page Content in typo3

Tags: typo3

How to export pages specific fields through extension in typo3
Only want to export below fields

```
Pages : title, page content
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is quite general. You can use the extension impexp to export pages and content (which is persisted in the table `tt_content`) or of course create a custom extension and do it with your own code.

Comment: Thanks , I want to export only content of pages not all fields of table, I have checked the impexp extension but in that we are just able to select the table names only not particular fields.. 
Can we have any alternative for that (any other extension)?